# Scifi book about brain implant stolen from the future, and implanted in an unsuspecting normal guy

Tags: story-identification, books

I must have read scifi book sometime in the early 80's, and from memory I'm guessing the book I'm looking for was written in the 60's or 70's.

From what I can remember, the plot was about a brain implant which, of course, grants superhuman mental abilities, being stolen by one of the protagonists. He/she then travels back in time with the implant to avoid capture and punishment by the authorities, and hides it by transplanting it into the brain of a new born baby or child (I cant remember which), where it is intended to be retrieved later.

The implant is not retrieved and the child grows up with world changing mental powers, (I remember him being able to rearrange his molecular structure and being able to walk through walls among other things), until the end of the book where the thief returns to retrieve the implant and a battle ensues.

Comment: After looking around, I wonder if it could be this? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169484/bank-cashier-brain-implant-computer-augment-evolution?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us. Additionally, if you become sure that that other link is what you were looking for, let us know and we can link this question to that answer by marking it a duplicate.

Comment: Englishbob, I remember reading the same book and have been looking for it as well. I believe the story takes place in London. The researcher who goes back in time, uses a combination of brain tissue of those of his time and an experimental type. He implants it into a newborn. The protagonist as he grows up suffers from severe migraines. He becomes a bank teller. One day, the migraines stop and he starts developing the mental powers, which are part of the normal future people's abilities. As I recall the researcher is executed by the governing council, because meddling in the past is forbidden.

Comment: @KenM did that link in the comment I posted to my own question ring any bells?...after looking at the cover and reading the blurb, I'm convinced that's the book "One Against Time" by Astron del Martia

Comment: Seeing the cover of the book linked in your comment as a possibility rang a bell: https://www.amazon.co.uk/One-Against-Time-Astron-Martia/dp/0583115225

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bank Cashier, Brain implant, Computer Augment, Evolution](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169484/bank-cashier-brain-implant-computer-augment-evolution)

Comment: I should have looked closer earlier. We can't mark as dup since the target does not have an accepted answer. Therefore, OP, I encourage you to post the answer below and mark it accepted.

Comment: I'm voting to leave open as there's not acceptance on either of these posts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the book you're looking for is **One Against Time** by *Astron del Martia*. You have the researcher; Bannister, who has stolen the implant and travels back in time, to put it in the brain of an infant; Harold Newman. The implant is the combination of brain tissue of someone from a thousand years in the future and an experimental "super brain X," The future brain allows telepathy, the experimental part allows control of the individual atoms and he's able to walk through a wall. A side effect of the implant was blinding headaches as each part of the implant began to integrate.

However in the book, Bannister doen't return for the implant, but a security team from the future captures Harold and wants to lobotomize the implant. Responding to the linked question; Harold is a bank teller,has trouble with numbers, his sense of aesthetics is heightened and the woman of current time look coarse. The twist with the female, he's becomes attracted to, is that, she's part of the security team from the future.

[image: One Against Time front cover 1] [image: One Against Time front cover 2]

Comment: Haha! thankyou for the answer! Confirms my previous research....and the cover on the right...I can just about remember it!

Comment: "being able to walk through walls among other things" ... I do that several times a day, I use a door